# Angularjs : $q called before promises are completed

Tags: angularjs

I have trouble using $q and promises.
I am doing this :

```
for (var i = 0; i<$scope.products.length; i++){
   var product = $scope.products[i];
   promises.push(Sale.save(product,function(result){
       $scope.listOfProducts.push(result);
   }));
}
$q.all(promises).then(function() {      
        echo('done');
    });
});
```

My problem is that echo('done') is called before all Sale.save are finished. 
I don't know why.

If anyone knows...
Thank you

Comment: If `Sale` is a `$resource`, then the promise is available via the `$promise` property of the returned object: `promises.push(Sale.save(...).$promise)`.

Comment: Can you share `save`'s code?

Comment: save is a resource that call a java controller

Comment: sp00m : my syntax is not right?

Comment: @user1260928 Try with using `$promise` as I said: line 5 = `}).$promise);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `Sale` is a resource, if that is the case, you need to handle the promise a little differently.

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i<$scope.products.length; i++){
   var product = $scope.products[i];
   promises.push(Sale.save(product).$promise.then(function(result){
       $scope.listOfProducts.push(result);
       return result;
   }));
}
$q.all(promises).then(function(results) {      
        echo('done');
    });
});
```

Comment: I have an error when adding .then : TypeError: undefined is not a function on the 'then' . Sale is a resource.

Comment: Can you add the code for `Sale`? Is it a `$resource`?

Comment: My bad, I just realized I missed `$promise`. Try it now.

Comment: .factory('Sale', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/sale/:id', {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET'
            }
        });
    })

Comment: Good, it seems to work well with $promise.then, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/UzXzq/19/) a rough example using `$timeout` to simulate the delay on each function process .

You should try to return each value on independent running circle in order to push the function into the promise queue:

```
promises.push($scope.testFuncToResolve(i).then(function (result) {
  //extra stuff here
  return result;
}));
```